# alternative regex to match all text in between first two dashes

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the following regex `\-(.*?)-|\-(.*?)*` it seems to work fine on [regexr](http://regexr.com/) but python says there's nothing to repeat?

I'm trying to match all text in between the first two dashes or if a second dash does not exist after the first all text from the first `-` onwards.

Also, the regex above includes the dashes, but would preferrably like to exclude these so I don't have to do an extra replace etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.search` with this pattern:

```
-([^-]*)
```

Note that `-` doesn't need to be escaped.

An other way consists to only search the positions of the two first dashes, and to extract the substring between these positions. Or you can use `split`:

```
>>> 'aaaaa-bbbbbb-ccccc-ddddd'.split('-')[1]
'bbbbbb'
```